# readfile not working properly

Tags: php, url, readfile

I'm trying to download a file through my server to me, by streaming the download.

This is my script:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=http://user:pass@example.com/file.bin';
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $r[2]);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($fileName);
exit;
```

example.com isn't what I'm really using, I just didn't want to show the real URL. :) When I go to this file in my web browser a download prompt does not come up and nothing happens. `$r[2]` is the content length in bytes of the file and `$fileName` is the same URL as used in the attachment header. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind your serving an absolute URL with username and password (?!?!?!) as the download file name. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Joseph: tags don't belong to subject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

readfile(); needs the absolute path of the file on the machine rather than a url.

e.g. /home/person/file.exe

Comment: Hi, I have tried this already and the script does still not work when I test it with a local file. Even if this did work, I still have the problem of opening a URL with readfile() don't I? php.net says this function accepts a URL but I can't get it to work. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: From the php function page "A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to specify the filename. See the List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide."

Answer (score 0):

There's a missing `)` at the end of the filename header line, but I'm assuming that happened when edited the line.

For what it's worth, running your sample code on gives a download prompt, haven't really tested it much past that, but maybe it's something with the server/client configuration - not the code.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the problem is the filesize, try to get the filesize over http (look at this function):
http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1214

So edit from

```
header('Content-Length: ' . $r[2]);
```

to

```
header('Content-Length: ' . get_remote_file_size($fileurl) );
```

Hope you solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to download an image for example, but this could help with any kind of file. It downloads a file without using `readfile`.

I know it can be clumsy but sometimes we need some workarounds to get the job done.

Try this, where `$src = 'http://external-server/remote-image.jpg'`

```
$url_stuff = parse_url($src); 
$port = isset($url_stuff['port']) ? $url_stuff['port'] : 80; 
$fp = fsockopen($url_stuff['host'], $port); 
$query  = 'GET ' . $url_stuff['path'] . " HTTP/1.0\n"; 
$query .= 'Host: ' . $url_stuff['host']; 
$query .= "\n\n"; 
$buffer=null;
fwrite($fp, $query); 
while ($tmp = fread($fp, 1024)) 
{ 
    $buffer .= $tmp; 
} 

preg_match('/Content-Length: ([0-9]+)/', $buffer, $parts); 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_file.bin');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

$content = substr($buffer, - $parts[1]); 
echo $content;
```

this is tested and working ;-)