# PHP stream PDF with fread and readfile produce a damaged pdf

Tags: php, pdf, readfile

Hello guys i have a  problem streaming PDF files with php, i'm using this code:

```
if(file_exists($path))
        {
            //octet-stream 
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize ( $path ) ); 
            header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
            header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($path)); 
            readfile($path);

        }
```

This is my directory layout (so you can understand where the PDF are stored):

```
Parent/
  verify.php
  auth/
    pdf/
    login.php
```

If i stream the a pdf from verify.php all works as intended... but if i stream the SAME PDF file from login.php they are corrupted (damaged).

Here my path definition in login.php

```
$path = "pdf/" . $filename . "_print.pdf";
```

And here my path definition in verify.php

```
$path = "auth/pdf/" . $filename . "_print.pdf";
```

Obviosly path definition is before che stream code.

The average dimension of pdf files are up to 50Kb.

The file exists beacuse pass the if check but i've no clue about why in one place is ok and in the other is damaged. (i've checked the file into the directory are okay).

Sorry for my poor english and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i fixed the issue editing the code like this:

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize ( $path ) ); 
                header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
                header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($path));
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
                ob_clean();
                flush();

                readfile($path);
```

The path work in both ways: relative or absolute.

Thanks to:
[readfile not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861674/readfile-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 0):

Your current working derictory doesn't change depending on your **included** script path. So if `/var/www/parent/auth/login.php` is included by `/var/www/parent/index.php` your working directory will remain `/var/www/parent`.

The popular way to deal with this is to define a `define('BASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__));` (BASEPATH='/var/www/parent') constant in your main file, and use it everywhere else:

```
//in verify.php
$path = BASEPATH . "/auth/pdf/" . $filename . "_print.pdf";

//in login.php
$path = BASEPATH . "/auth/pdf/" . $filename . "_print.pdf";
```

Comment: Unfortunaltly, this is not the case 'coz the file aren't inclueded i call login.php directly.

However i've tried to specify the full path in $path like this:

`$path = "/home/eldblz/www/auth/pdf/" . $filename . "_print.pdf";`

("parent" was just for example purpose)
The script pass the file_exists check render the file but it's damaged.

Thank you anyway for your kind reply.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the last 2 sentences of your question... In this case probably something is corrupting data from login.php (some PHP notice or warning perhaps), so check your code. Open the downloaded from login.php file with notepad or something and search for 'notice/warning'. Or if you have something to compare 2 files (like total commander) you could compare files downloaded through `verify` and `login` scripts, and find where the problem is.